# Holomorphic vs Analytic functions in multiple complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis

I think I have seen somewhere that for functions of more than one complex variables, smooth holomorphic (i.e. infinitely differentiable) no longer implies analyticity (i.e. having power series expansion locally) but I do not find any examples of this. Can anyone give me an example of a function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ that is smooth i.e. $\frac{\partial^m f}{\partial^{m_1} z_1 \partial^{m_2} z_2 \cdots \partial^{m_n} z_n}$ exists for all $k, m_1, ..., m_n$ such that $m_1 + \cdots + m_n = k$ but that it does not have power series expansion at a point $p \in U$?

Comment: It seems the distinction is more found in the possibility of extending all analytic functions past a given domain. In the one complex dimensional case there exist analytic functions on the unit-disk which cannot be continued past the disk. In several complex variables there exist domains for which all analytic functions can be continued.

Answer (score 1):

A corolary of Harthog's theorem is that if $f$ is analytic on each variable then is analytic in the $n$-variable sense. Therefore, such an example shouldn't exist. 
see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs%27s_theorem